# For Loops for multiple choice questions?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Building a quiz. I have 4 multiple choice options I want to populate with JS. Each choice has text, and a corresponding icon. I have the questions section working, but I can't seem to get the choices working. I'm trying to iterate through the 4 options (each option has a data value assigned to it that at the end, determines your answer) but I can't access the choices out of the nested array, even when I'm just console.log(questions[0][1]); Any suggestions? Should I be using a different kind of for loop? Should I break up the array and loop through everything separately(which doesn't seem very efficient)?

```js
let questions = [{
    question: "Do you mind crowds?",
    icons: {
      choice1: "Q1_A.svg",
      choice2: "Q1_B.svg",
      choice3: "Q1_C.svg",
      choice4: "Q1_D.svg",
    },
    choices: {
      choice1: "Crowds don't bother me",
      choice2: "I prefer to get off the beaten path",
      choice3: "I don't care either way",
      choice4: "Crowds mean there is something worth looking at",
    }
  },
  {
    question: "Where would you like to stay on your trip?",
    icons: {
      choice1: "Q2_A.svg",
      choice2: "Q2_B.svg",
      choice3: "Q2_C.svg",
      choice4: "Q2_D.svg",
    },
    choices: {
      choice1: "Crowds don't bother me",
      choice2: "I prefer to get off the beaten path",
      choice3: "I don't care either way",
      choice4: "Crowds mean there is something worth looking at",
    }
  },
  {
    question: "What activities do you enjoy?",
    icons: {
      choice1: "Q3_A.svg",
      choice2: "Q3_B.svg",
      choice3: "Q3_C.svg",
      choice4: "Q3_D.svg",
    },
    choices: {
      choice1: "Crowds don't bother me",
      choice2: "I prefer to get off the beaten path",
      choice3: "I don't care either way",
      choice4: "Crowds mean there is something worth looking at",
    }
  }
];

//Convert to an array, so you can use array functions on it
const choice = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('choice_text'));

choicesCounter = 0;

choicesLoop = () => {
  choice.forEach(choice => {
    const number = choice.dataset['number'];
    choice.innerHTML = questions.choices['choice' + number];
    choicesCounter++;
  });
};
```

```html
<div class="multiple-choice-container">
  <div class="choice_container">
    <p class="choice_icon" data-number='1'>A</p>
    <p class="choice_text" data-number='1'> Choice 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="choice_container ">
    <p class="choice_icon" data-number='2'>B</p>
    <p class="choice_text" data-number='2'> Choice 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="choice_container">
    <p class="choice_icon" data-number='3'>C</p>
    <p class="choice_text" data-number='3'> Choice 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="choice_container">
    <p class="choice_icon" data-number='4'>D</p>
    <p class="choice_text" data-number='4'> Choice 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to pass the question number you're displaying into your `choicesLoop` (or perhaps thats what `choicesCounter`  was in your code but you forgot to use it in the right place)

```
choicesLoop = (questionId) => {
  choice.forEach(choice => {
    const number = choice.dataset['number'];
    choice.innerHTML = questions[questionId].choices['choice' + number];
    choicesCounter++;
  });
};
```

or

```
choicesLoop = () => {
  choice.forEach(choice => {
    const number = choice.dataset['number'];
    choice.innerHTML = questions[choicesCounter].choices['choice' + number];
    choicesCounter++;
  });
};
```

```js
let questions = [{
    question: "Do you mind crowds?",
    icons: {
      choice1: "Q1_A.svg",
      choice2: "Q1_B.svg",
      choice3: "Q1_C.svg",
      choice4: "Q1_D.svg",
    },
    choices: {
      choice1: "Crowds don't bother me",
      choice2: "I prefer to get off the beaten path",
      choice3: "I don't care either way",
      choice4: "Crowds mean there is something worth looking at",
    }
  },
  {
    question: "Where would you like to stay on your trip?",
    icons: {
      choice1: "Q2_A.svg",
      choice2: "Q2_B.svg",
      choice3: "Q2_C.svg",
      choice4: "Q2_D.svg",
    },
    choices: {
      choice1: "Crowds don't bother me",
      choice2: "I prefer to get off the beaten path",
      choice3: "I don't care either way",
      choice4: "Crowds mean there is something worth looking at",
    }
  },
  {
    question: "What activities do you enjoy?",
    icons: {
      choice1: "Q3_A.svg",
      choice2: "Q3_B.svg",
      choice3: "Q3_C.svg",
      choice4: "Q3_D.svg",
    },
    choices: {
      choice1: "Crowds don't bother me",
      choice2: "I prefer to get off the beaten path",
      choice3: "I don't care either way",
      choice4: "Crowds mean there is something worth looking at",
    }
  }
];

//Convert to an array, so you can use array functions on it
const choice = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('choice_text'));

choicesCounter = 0;

choicesLoop = (questionId) => {
  choice.forEach(choice => {
    const number = choice.dataset['number'];
    choice.innerHTML = questions[questionId].choices['choice' + number];
    choicesCounter++;
  });
};

choicesLoop(0)
```

```html
<div class="multiple-choice-container">
  <div class="choice_container">
    <p class="choice_icon" data-number='1'>A</p>
    <p class="choice_text" data-number='1'> Choice 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="choice_container ">
    <p class="choice_icon" data-number='2'>B</p>
    <p class="choice_text" data-number='2'> Choice 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="choice_container">
    <p class="choice_icon" data-number='3'>C</p>
    <p class="choice_text" data-number='3'> Choice 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="choice_container">
    <p class="choice_icon" data-number='4'>D</p>
    <p class="choice_text" data-number='4'> Choice 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Secondary question (if you have time/know off the top of your head). I made the second loop for the icons (which also works). The icons are svgs, stored in a folder. The "Q1_A.svg" appears, but I can't seem to dynamically insert the icons, themselves. I've also tried object literals to drop the selected item in the array into a pathway icon.innerHTML = /icons/`${questions[choicesCounter].icons['choice' + number]}` but that doesn't work either. Any suggestions?

Comment: @HappyHobbit you're better off asking a new question with a [mcve] to demonstrate the problem

Comment: Done! I'm new, so that's good advice and I'll definitely remember that for future questions. Thanks!